# Why am I receiving an operation failed error when trying to set up a new project?

Tags: azure-devops, project, operation

I am trying to set up a new project and I receive the below error. I hit "retry" but the error shows again. I have tried in different browsers & cleared all cache but issue continues.

"Oops, something went wrong. Project creation operation failed. Please retry project creation."
CTA: Try again

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your issue may have something to do with your custom process template. `Azure Devops` supports default processes like `Basic, Agile, Scrum, and CMMI`, also it supports customize an inherited process.

Check which process model do you select when you create the project, I think the issue would go away if you select the default process to create the project. And that issue occurs when you try to create one project based on bad process model.

When you create the project, test with different WIT and you can locate the bad one:

[image]

Hope it helps and if i misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Hi Lance. Thank you so much. This did work. I created a custom process under "basic" and it sounds like there is an issue with that. Do you know how I can find the issue within my customer process? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I'm not certainly sure about where the issue exists in your process. Can you share some details about how you define the custom process(simple steps to help us reproduce the issue)? Also you can try to create a new custom process with similar content to check if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi. I actually just made a copy of it and added that to the new projects. This seems to be working for now. Again appreciate your help!

Comment: @JKillia Does this issue persist to block you?If my answer helps to resolve this issue, please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.